# jQuery .slideUp() not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, slideup

I'm trying to make an accordion like section to a page I'm working on. I'm not using jQueries native accordion plugin because I need the ability to close all the sections. My problem is Chrome doesn't seem to be responding to `.slideUp()` while everything seems to work perfectly in Firefox and IE. Rather than try and copy all the relative code snippets I just uploaded here http://ianburris.com/p/tmp/. Any ideas what might be causing this in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `<div>` for your containers rather than a `<span>` here, [here's your code](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/rJffu/2/) (forget the styling, focus on the sliding) as it is, not working with a `<span>` in chrome.

[Here's the working version](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/rJffu/), the only change is making the element's blocks, `<div>` elements in this case.

These:

```
<span id="in-the-classroom" class="menu-pane"> 
//and
<span id="outside-the-classroom" class="menu-pane">
```

Should be:

```
<div id="in-the-classroom" class="menu-pane"> 
//and
<div id="outside-the-classroom" class="menu-pane">
```

And of course the matching `</span>` to `</div>` changes.

Comment: Wow, I got bit by this one! Fortunately my architecture *(for a WordPress plugin)* doesn't *require* `<span>` tags so I was able to change over.  THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
 if (cfe.active_menu_pane !== null)
```

to

```
 if (cfe.active_menu_pane != null) // Remove the second equal sign
```

Not sure it would matter but it was the one irregularity I saw in a function.