# jQuery SlideUp doesn't work well in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, slideup

I have a `div`, and following it is a `ul`.

I apply `slideDown` to the `div`, and that pushes the `ul` down nicely, in all browsers.

However, when I apply `slideUp` to the `div`, in all broswers the `ul` comes up nicely *after*
the `div` has finished sliding up, but in Chrome, the `ul` comes up *while* the `div` is sliding up, and then it looks messy for a few seconds until the `div` disappears.

You can see an example [here](http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/):

The `slideDown` and `slideUp` are activated when you click this image:
[image]

It makes this div appear or disappear:
[image]

And this is the `ul` that is supposed to go down and up when that div appears and disappears, respectively:
[image]

And here is the code. The HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix" id="whatWhere">
<ul>
<!--what-->
    <li id="what">
        <span>מה</span>
         <div class="list">
            <ul class="">
              <li class="orange"><a href="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges?cat=7">אדריכלות ועיצוב פנים</a></li>
              <li class="gray"><a href="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges?cat=14">אלקטרוניקה</a></li>
              </ul>    
             <div class="toClose">
             <img width="37" height="18" src="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/close.png">
             </div>
            </div><!--end list-->
    </li>
 <!-- where -->
    <li id="where">
            <span>איפה</span>
            <div class="list">
            <ul class="">
                <li class="orange"><a href="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/?p=21">מכללת אורט כפר סבא</a></li>
                <li class="gray"><a href="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/?p=19">מכללת אורט קרית ביאליק</a></li>
            </ul>

                 <div class="toClose">
             <img width="37" height="18" src="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/close.png">
             </div>
                </div><!--end list-->
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>

<ul id="links">
   <li id="hashlama"><a href="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/?p=161">השלמה לתואר ראשון להנדסאים</a></li>
   <li id="michlalot"><a href="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/?p=165">מכללות אקדמיות להנדסה</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
                  $(document).ready(function() {  
                  $("#whatWhere ul li  span").click(function () {
                      //if another li open- closed;
                    if($(this).parent().siblings().children(".list").hasClass("highlight")){
                        // $(this).parent().siblings().children("ul").slideUp("slow"); 
                        $(this).parent().siblings().children(".list").css("display","none"); 
                         $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("open");
                         $(this).parent().siblings().addClass("standBy");
                         $(this).parent().siblings().children(".list").toggleClass("highlight");   
                    } 
                    //open ul of selected li area
                    $(this).next().toggleClass("highlight");   
                    if($(this).next().hasClass("highlight"))
                        {
                        //#whatWhere
                            $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("open");
                            //li
                             $(this).parent().addClass("open");
                             $(this).next().slideDown("slow");
                             $(this).parent().siblings().addClass("standBy");
                             $(this).parent().removeClass("standBy");
                        }
                    else
                        {
                         $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass("open");
                         //li
                             $(this).parent().removeClass("open");
                         $(this).next().slideUp("slow"); 
                        // $(this).next().css("display","none"); 
                         $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("standBy");
                         $(this).parent().removeClass("standBy");
                        }
                    }); 

                    $("#whatWhere ul li  .list  div.toClose").click(function () {
                         $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().removeClass("open"); /*div #whatWhere*/
                             $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("open"); /*li #what/#where*/
                         $(this).parent().slideUp("slow"); 

                         $(this).parent().parent().siblings().removeClass("standBy");/* the other li #what/#where*/
                          $(this).parent().toggleClass("highlight");   /* div .list - maybe not needed*/
                    }); 
                });
```

Comment: Always post the relevant markup and code **in the question itself**, don't just link (*also* linking is fine). Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: @T.J. Crowder You're right, and I usually do, but this time the code was so long (both the HTML and the JS), that I was afraid it would confuse rather than help...

Comment: @ Lea: Still better to include it. Just make sure your actual question is at the top, then paste the code and markup in at the bottom. As it is now, this question is useless for anyone with a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "height: auto" to your div with id "whatWhere" permanently and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot @helmus, That solved the problem! Could you explain how you got to this solution?

Comment: Glad i could help Lea ! I used chrome dev tools to monitor the changes that occurred during the animation. I then noticed that the "open" css class in "style.css" is removed right before the div collapses, this class has "height: auto" as one of it's style property's, changing the whatWhere class to match it then fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835658/jquery-slideup-not-working-in-chrome) guy seems to have got it running in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, but this wasn't helpful in my case, since the element being applied to was already a div

Comment: I fixed in now, according to @helmus's answer

Answer (score 0):

You should add the showing of the `ul` in the callback of the showing the `div`.

```
$('#yourDiv').slideUp(normal, function() {
    $('#yourUl').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not use JS to fix what seems to really be a CSS problem