# jQuery SlideDown in IE8 doesn't push down the next element

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, slidedown, slideup

have a `div`, and following it is a `ul`.

I apply `slideDown` to the `div`, and that pushes the `ul` down nicely in all browsers except in IE8, where the `div` covers the `ul`.

When I apply `slideUp` to the div, *then* the `ul` slides down - leaving a big gap between it and the former element.

Has anyone run into this behavior? What could be causing it?

You can see an example [here](http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/):

The `slideDown` and `slideUp` are activated when you click this image:
[image]

It makes this div appear or disappear:
[image]

And this is the `ul` that is supposed to go down and up when that div appears and disappears, respectively:
[image]

And here is the code. The HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix" id="whatWhere">
<ul>
<!--what-->
    <li id="what">
        <span>מה</span>
         <div class="list">
            <ul class="">
              <li class="orange"><a href="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges?cat=7">אדריכלות ועיצוב פנים</a></li>
              <li class="gray"><a href="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges?cat=14">אלקטרוניקה</a></li>
              </ul>    
             <div class="toClose">
             <img width="37" height="18" src="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/close.png">
             </div>
            </div><!--end list-->
    </li>
 <!-- where -->
    <li id="where">
            <span>איפה</span>
            <div class="list">
            <ul class="">
                <li class="orange"><a href="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/?p=21">מכללת אורט כפר סבא</a></li>
                <li class="gray"><a href="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/?p=19">מכללת אורט קרית ביאליק</a></li>
            </ul>

                 <div class="toClose">
             <img width="37" height="18" src="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/close.png">
             </div>
                </div><!--end list-->
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>

<ul id="links">
   <li id="hashlama"><a href="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/?p=161">השלמה לתואר ראשון להנדסאים</a></li>
   <li id="michlalot"><a href="http://dev.linux.ort.org.il/colleges/?p=165">מכללות אקדמיות להנדסה</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
                  $(document).ready(function() {  
                  $("#whatWhere ul li  span").click(function () {
                      //if another li open- closed;
                    if($(this).parent().siblings().children(".list").hasClass("highlight")){
                        // $(this).parent().siblings().children("ul").slideUp("slow"); 
                        $(this).parent().siblings().children(".list").css("display","none"); 
                         $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("open");
                         $(this).parent().siblings().addClass("standBy");
                         $(this).parent().siblings().children(".list").toggleClass("highlight");   
                    } 
                    //open ul of selected li area
                    $(this).next().toggleClass("highlight");   
                    if($(this).next().hasClass("highlight"))
                        {
                        //#whatWhere
                            $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("open");
                            //li
                             $(this).parent().addClass("open");
                             $(this).next().slideDown("slow");
                             $(this).parent().siblings().addClass("standBy");
                             $(this).parent().removeClass("standBy");
                        }
                    else
                        {
                         $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass("open");
                         //li
                             $(this).parent().removeClass("open");
                         $(this).next().slideUp("slow"); 
                        // $(this).next().css("display","none"); 
                         $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("standBy");
                         $(this).parent().removeClass("standBy");
                        }
                    }); 

                    $("#whatWhere ul li  .list  div.toClose").click(function () {
                         $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().removeClass("open"); /*div #whatWhere*/
                             $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("open"); /*li #what/#where*/
                         $(this).parent().slideUp("slow"); 

                         $(this).parent().parent().siblings().removeClass("standBy");/* the other li #what/#where*/
                          $(this).parent().toggleClass("highlight");   /* div .list - maybe not needed*/
                    }); 
                });
```

(I asked a [question about the same code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9989910/278) a while ago (and got a good answer), but there the problem was in Chrome, and the problematic behavior was different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-writing the HTML, so the `div` with class="list" was outside the `li`'s with the id's "when" and "where". I of course altered the JavaScript too, to accommodate this change, and that solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the problem appeared to be related to usage of rounded-corners

```
behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
```

My wild guess is that any CSS's behaviour directive would cause the trouble.